# ReactJS - Showing Column Name

Tags: reactjs

**EDIT**

I am completely new to ReactJS, please bear with my stupidity.

Recently I have been playing around with ReactJS and PHP, and currently stuck on map.()

**App.Js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            uNames:[]
        };

        this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    }
    submitData=()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost/public/api/data.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({uNames: result});
            console.log(this.state.uNames);
       })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.submitData}>Test</Button>
                {this.state.uNames.map((uName, i) => 
                    <Table key={i}>
                        <thead>
                            <td key={uName[i]}>
                                {uName[i]}
                            </td>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                {uName.id}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                {uName.firstname}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                {uName.lastname}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
}

$serverName = "localhost";
$serverUserName = "root";
$serverPassword = "";
$dbName = "test";
$connection = new mysqli ($serverName, $serverUserName, $serverPassword, $dbName);

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM mydata";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$connection->close();
?>
```

**MYSQL(table mydata)**

```
id|firstname|lastname
1 |     John|     Doe
```

The row data(**1,John,Doe**) showing just fine, but for the column header(**ID, FirstName, LastName**), nothing's there.

Is it possible so the column header shows up(it reads dynamically from MySQL table) or it is only possible by setting every single column header as static content?

Comment: Can you show an example how the `this.state.uNames` looks like? Thanks!

Comment: in my browser console.log() it shows something like this

0: {…}
​​
0: "1"
​​
1: "John"
​​
2: "Doe"
​​
firstname: "John"
​​
id: "1"
​​
lastname: "Doe"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1

Comment: As you are not getting header data. you have to make it static.

Comment: That what @mayank-pandeyz explained to me. Thanks for the help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code logic and question, `uNames` is an array of object and you are using `map` to iterate over array and get individual objects and from which you are showing name etc by this code:

```
uName.id
uName.firstname
```

etc and which is working fine. In that case you cant use:

```
uName[i]
```

as uName is an object under map and it is having keys like id, firstname etc and not having numeric keys that's why you are not getting anything. 
I hope this will help you in understanding the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see! So I can only set the column header as static text. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nicholas You can [iterate over the property/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) if you'd like to dynamically create headers and data fields.